# How to create a solid DropShadow effect on a translucent background in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm having a strange `DropShadow` effect when applying it to a node with translucent background color as you can see in this image:

[image]

The upper node has a solid background color while the other one has the semi transparent background color. Both of them has the same exact effect, but the second one appeared too blurry. How can I correct this?

---

## EDIT

Here's a working demo:

```
public class App extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    // The drop shadow effect.
    DropShadow effect = new DropShadow();
    effect.setBlurType(BlurType.GAUSSIAN);
    effect.setColor(Color.rgb(0,0,0, .5));
    effect.setSpread(0);
    effect.setOffsetX(0);
    effect.setOffsetY(7);

    // Node with solid background color.
    Button button1 = new Button("BUTTON");
    VBox.setMargin(button1, new Insets(0, 0, 15, 0));
    button1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(238,238,238);");
    button1.setEffect(effect);

    // Node with translucent background color.
    Button button2 = new Button("BUTTON");
    VBox.setMargin(button2, new Insets(15, 0, 0, 0));
    button2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(238,238,238, .5);");
    button2.setEffect(effect);

    VBox root = new VBox(button1, button2);
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(15));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: What code are you using to apply the drop shadows?

Comment: @Vulcan The [`DropShadow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/effect/DropShadow.html) effect.

Comment: Please include example code so others can easily reproduce the issue. I just finished reproducing it successfully but you can save future viewers time by supplying them with the example code.

Comment: @Vulcan Okay. I'm editing my question now. I will remember that as well.

Comment: One idea that comes to mind is placing the button in a `StackPane` and applying the shadow to that instead. So far I have been able to get the shadow to work correctly but I have not been able to manage the size correctly. I'm not too familiar with JavaFX though, maybe you will be able to solve it with this approach.

Comment: If you are able to solve the problem, remember to answer your own question with the solution for future viewers :)

Comment: I guess there's no other choice for now... The downside is, not only it'll cost an extra layer but it may also affect the desired background color (that could be an issue if you're working on a theme).